# How do I bind/map shortcut with a function key?

Tags: wix

I have a shortcut installed on the desktop through Wix. How can I associate the shortcut with the function key F4.
i.e shortcut should be launched when the user press F4.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Shortcut>` element has an optional `Hotkey` attribute:

> The hotkey for the shortcut. The low-order byte contains the
>   virtual-key code for the key, and the high-order byte contains
>   modifier flags. This must be a non-negative number. Authors of
>   installation packages are generally recommend not to set this option,
>   because this can add duplicate hotkeys to a users desktop. In
>   addition, the practice of assigning hotkeys to shortcuts can be
>   problematic for users using hotkeys for accessibility.

Have you tried it out? Pay attention to the warning concerning setting hotkeys for shortcuts.

Comment: As I can see from the Virtual key table F4 key value is 73 in hexadecimal which comes out to be 115 in decimal. And I have used the following code but F4 was not assigned for the shortcut:   <Shortcut Id="ProgramMenuShortcutMyproject"
                          Target="[MyprojectSplashFolder] Myproject.exe"
                          Name="$(var.ProductName)"
                          Description="Launch $(var.ProductName)"
                          WorkingDirectory="MyprojectSplashFolder"
                          Hotkey="115"
                          Icon="marvin.ico"/> Is it right?

Comment: When the shortcut is created, what value is there in the Hotkey field? I doubt you can use F4 for this purpose - you can't even enter it manually to the desktop shortcut. When you enter a letter there, it automatically becomes Ctrl + Alt + <letter>